# Emulate/Simulate iPhone Sprinboard behavior in a JS Webpage

Tags: php, javascript, iphone, html, web-applications

I am looking for a smart way to emulate the iPhone Springboard behavior of changing icon possition. I just want to change few icons on ONE screen. 
It should be run in JS on a webpage. 
Any suggestions to start?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [jQuery UI Sortable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable) will be good for that.

Check [this demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#display-grid). If you would add icons to the elements in that demo and style it a bit I think you would get what you want.